# Firefox shows background image black

Tags: html, css

I have made a background image for whole page. Its Ok with other browsers but in Firefox the background image is not showing instead whole background is black.
here is my css:

```
html { 
    background: url(../images/bglogin.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;

    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../images/bglogin.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src=../'images/bglogin.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
}
```

Comment: Below you mention you're looking at it on Firefox v11. Firefox is currently on V18. Might be worth upgrading? You could try placing the word 'transparent' (without the quotes) before url in your background property.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
html { 
     background-image:url('images/bglogin.jpg');
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
     background-attachment:fixed;
     background-position:center; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;

    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../images/bglogin.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src=../'images/bglogin.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
}
```

Comment: Pawan i have checked the path its correct background image is  rendering in Chrome and IE Properly but not in FireFox version eleven. I have googled about it they say try to install new add on. Did it Still not working.